# Why the output is "threefour" when the index of the array is 3 and “seveneightnine” when the index is 7?

Tags: c

The size of the array “ones” is 10 and each can have maximum 5 characters. Output of ones[3] is ”threefour”, the max characters can be 5, and the size of “three” in ones[3] is 5. Why it prints”threefour” for ones[3]?
The code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    char input[8];
    printf("Enter the integer: ");
    scanf("%c",input);
    char ones[10][5]={"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};
    printf("%d\n",input[0]-'0');
    puts(ones[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
Enter the integer: 3
3
threefour

Comment: Do not post your code as image. Please post your code as text directly in your question.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a code sample

Comment: Thanks Ohad Eytan, I will surely read that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by having `puts()` access out-of-range. Each elements of `ones` have only 5 elements, so there will be no room to store a terminating null-charcter when you try to store `"three"` there. Allocate one more element (i.e. use `ones[10][6]`) to avoid that.

Comment: In array when we mention the size as 5 then 0-4 are for data and 5th is '\0', right? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Are you sure this is _undefined behavior_? To my knowledge the shape of memory of 2-dim array is well defined so the last null-character invade to `ones[4][0]` and then overwrite by the `f` of `"four"`

Comment: @Ankesh In array of size 5 there is no array[5] since that would be 6th element. Last element is array[4].

Comment: @OhadEytan Yes. Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) J.2 Undefined behavior: "An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the
given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1][7] given the declaration int
a[4][5]) (6.5.6)."